# Figures moving out of order

Tags: floats

This the first document I am making in LaTeX and I am having some problems with the images.

As you can see, I placed the figure in section "Metologia y Procedimiento" but it goes to the top of that page right after the first image in section "Marco Teorico". I saw some answers on other forums/pages but they required to get rid of the captions (as I understood it) but the captions are required by my professor.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}

% % %Package loading
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{gensymb}
```

Here is the part that is giving me problems (i substituted the text for something random to avoid being lengthy):

```
\section{Marco Teórico}

 Random Paragraph

\begin{figure} 
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=0.57\textwidth]{diferenciales}
\caption[Long caption]{Elemento de fuerza hidrostática sobre una placa plana}
\label{fig: diferenciales}
\end{figure}

\section{Objetivos}

\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 3
\item Item 3
\end{itemize}

\section{Metodología y Procedimiento}

Random paragraph

\begin{figure} 
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Equipo}
\caption[Long caption]{Equipo utilizado para la medición de fuerzas hidroestáticas}
\label{fig: equipo}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Datos y Ejemplos del Laboratorio}
```

Thank you in advance.

[image: First Page]

[image: Second Page]

Comment: The `figure` environment is a "floating" environment, which means that LaTeX moves it around the document where it fits best. If you absolutely want it to be placed where you said, just use the `center` environment instead of `figure`. If you do that and still want captions, you can look into the [`capt-of`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) package.

Comment: Thanks Paul I will look into it. I also read that LaTeX will place the image where it "thinks" it will go best. Is that placement really the best when it comes to that lab report? (Sorry for the double question, but I don't think that should be a whole new post.)

Comment: If you don't want figures to float "backwards" to the top of the current page add `\usepackage{flafter}`

Comment: Inti, there are ways to suggest good positions for the float algorithm to work with, you can take a look at [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017) for the full gory detail. :-)

Comment: @PaulGessler Note Frank's answer does not mention the answer for this question, which is flafter

Answer (score 4):

I went another route and used the [H] option for the float and added \usepackage{float} to the document.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Equipo}
\caption[Long caption]{Equipo utilizado para la medición de fuerzas hidroestáticas}
\label{fig: equipo}
\end{figure}
```

The second answer on [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat) led me to this solution.

[image]